# Routing Error rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

At this time I added a new route in config/routes.rb this way

```
resources :users do
    get "newasignacion" => "users#newasignacion", :as => "newasignacion"
end
```

And the link is this way

```
= link_to "Asignar Tarea", user_newasignacion_path(@user),
                        :class  => 'btn btn-success btn-mini' %>
```

But when I access the link i get this link:

```
http://localhost:3003/users/%23%3CActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User:0xa6c7f3c%3E/newasignacion
```

Can somebody tellme why is this problem ?

It should be like that `http://localhost:3003/users/5/newasignacion`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever is assigned to `@user` is an class type `ActiveRecord::Relation`, when it should be an instance of `User`. For the sake of illustration, see how passing `User.first` to your link helper outputs a valid link:

```
= link_to "Asignar Tarea", user_newasignacion_path(User.first),
                        :class  => 'btn btn-success btn-mini' %>
```

Verify that you're correctly assigning a user to `@user` in whatever controller action is rendering out the view in question.

Comment: mmm thanks man i just changed by <%= link_to "Asignar Tarea", user_newasignacion_path(user),
                        :class  => 'btn btn-success btn-mini' %> an it works :)